# Android notification channel maximum count

Tags: push-notification, android-notifications

I am new to implement Android notification channel in Oreo. What is the maximum number of notification channels for a single application. Can we create unlimited channels or it has some count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is **no limit on the number of channels an app can create**. The only purpose of NotificationChannel is to give more control of notification behavior to the user. It is no way to reduce the number of notification per app.

You can read about Notification Channel in detail at [Create and Display Notification on Android Oreo | With Example](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/creating-notification-channels-on-android-oreo-with-example/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit that is not documented on the number of channels you can have at the same time, but no limit on how many times you can create a channel, as long as you have deleted other channels.

The file `PreferencesHelper.java` contains a limit that is currently set to 50.000

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/PreferencesHelper.java

[image]

And this is being used to restrict the creation of more channels when it goes over that limit, throwing the exception `"Limit exceed; cannot create more channels"`
[image]

Unfortunately that value is not publicly accessible, so any limit check you might want to implement will have to be hardcoded by yourself. My suggestion is to set your own limit to a number that you think starts being unreasonable, and when that is reached you run a check on your notification channels to figure out what is going on, and fix it. For example, if your app will never need more than 5 channels to be created, then setting the limit to 6 would be a good way to start.

Answer (score -1):

Coming with **Android Oreo**, Notification Channels are something a developer uses to break down the notifications his or her app can give to us by type. The channels are decided by the people doing the developing, and the idea is to give us a way to separate out the notifications that are important to us from the ones that aren't, then decide how they will be shown. Some apps will have a lot of different channels. Some will have just a few and some will have only one.

In versions of Android before **O**, a developer used what was called a priority level to decide how to show you a notification. If they felt the notification was important, they could set it to peek (show a visual indication on your screen) or make a sound, or both. If they felt it wasn't it would just be placed in the tray for you to see the next time you went through them.

Now they break things out into channels and we get to decide how each type of notification is displayed. All notifications of the same type (for example, a reply on your Twitter feed) are placed into the same channel without any other types of notification grouped with them.

As a bonus, apps that allow us to use more than one account can have channels for each combined — your personal email and work email can follow the same rules and show you things the same way no matter which accounts received the notification.

**You should read this:**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. but i want to know the limitation of notification channel count. I searched more sites (including developer.android.com), no one described regarding notification count.

Answer (score -1):

The commit https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/f528b337dd48b7e8071269e07e610bd4a3668c75 update the max notification channel to 5.000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).